# Question and idea regarding local-only git tracked files

Tags: git

The commonly accepted practice to locally track files in git, but never push them to the shared remote repository, seems to be creating a separate git repository for local-only files.  This is something that is an OK workaround, but seems like overkill and is a bit cumbersome and complex when it comes to atomic commits and local branch merging.

It would be great if there was something like a .gitlocal file that supports globs like .gitignore but defines what is local-only for git.  All local repository behavior would be normal for files that match the globs in .gitlocal including versioning, branching, merging, etc.  But they would be treated as if they were in .gitignore for any remote pushes and pulls.

My primary use case is certain environment-specific files that should never be pushed to the shared repository, but for which local versioning is needed.

Another valuable use case is to have some new code work-in-progress that includes some entirely new code (maybe it is a plugin and config for a new feature). Yes, that can be developed in a new branch.  But what if I want to test that same code across multiple branches? git stash, or git checkout across branches might work but is a bit cumbersome.

With something like .gitlocal, I can merge my code locally into any branches that I want to test and maintain that WiP in git as I find and fix bugs in various branches, merging that code locally as needed.

Another interesting idea for .gitlocal is the shared repository might also define a .gitlocal (say for configuration files) with initial resources that will be copied upon cloning a repository but would never be overwritten (unless someone deletes the .gitlocal and commits to update the common config).

Are there any solutions other than the additional repository subtree or submodule approach?

Comment: No, there isn't. A commit is a full snapshot of its tree and a reference to its parent commit(s). "[…] behavior would be normal, including versioning, branching, merging […] except for pushing" isn't possible with Git's object format.

Comment: See [“Precious”](https://lore.kernel.org/git/pull.1627.git.1703643931314.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/). That proposal would be the closest you would get (if implemented). However that just keeps “precious” files, it doesn’t allow for versioning them.

Comment: So I would still use: `.git-local` or something repository. A completely parallel history without any of the mess of trying to keep a local-only history on top of a snapshot-based system, which is just hopeless unless you want to rebase every day.

Comment: Git should store source code necessary for a *build* tool. Environment-specific files sound like *configuration* that should be stored in a separate repository for use by a *deployment* tool. Your feature branch can be merged more than one branch for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have objects that are only local because that necessitates a different history.  All objects in Git are identified by a hash of their contents.  All commits refer to the parent tree, and all trees refer to their child trees or blobs.  Thus, if you change whether a file is included, you change one or more trees, and thus change the commit (and any commits that include it), so you have a different history.

However, you can create local-only repositories under the tree without making them submodules if you put them in `.gitignore`.  The repository will continue to be there as long as you don't delete it or run `git clean` with two `-f` arguments.

Note that for the initial resources or config files scenario, the [approach the Git FAQ recommends](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) is creating a template file and then using a script to copy it into the ignored destination location.  You can even create a script which takes the template file and an optional user configuration file (and maybe other files) and merges them, so the user can persist their local config and still regenerate with template updates as well.

Comment: That's not a "local-only" repository; that's just a directory full of files with no source control whatsoever.

Comment: That's not true at all.  You can go `git init subdir && echo "/subdir" >>.gitignore`, and that does indeed create a repository in `subdir`.  You can commit and work with it like a normal repo.  Granted, it is not tracked as part of the main repo, but it is nevertheless a local-only repository.

Comment: Oh, you are talking about actual separate repositories. They technically have nothing to do with the repository whose working directory *their* working directories are located. (I read "local-only repository" but was still thinking "local-only files".)

Comment: Yes, I wondered if that would be a limitation to my idea since commits and change hashes are essentially universal.  And I figured there is a  good reason for the most common solution to this problem being another repository.

Comment: This has been a useful thought experiment for me as I better understand using an additional repository.  It wouldn't make sense to have a commit that includes .gitlocal only and common files that are in local and remote repositories since there couldn't be a hash computed for a commit that would be the same in both places.